# Receive the total sum score of every number

Tags: r

Using as input data frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame(num = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3))
```

How is it possible to receive the sum of every number excited in the num column?

Example output:

```
num frequency
1 3
2 3
3 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `table` and coerce it to a data frame.

```
as.data.frame(table(df1$num))
#   Var1 Freq
# 1    1    3
# 2    2    3
# 3    3    1
```

or

```
with(df1, data.frame(num=unique(num), freq=tabulate(num)))
#   num freq
# 1   1    3
# 2   2    3
# 3   3    1
```